# Why doesn't Rust stop me from declaring multiple mutable references?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I am learning Rust from [*The Rust Programming Language*](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/) and I am having a WTF moment when code that is not supposed to compile is compiling.

[Rust has a rule that you can have only 1 mutable reference to a given data in a particular scope.](https://doc.rust-lang.org/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html) Which means this code isn't suppose to compile:

```
fn main() {
    let mut s1 = String::from("Hello");

    let r1 = &mut s1;
    let r2 = &mut s1;

    //println!("{} {}", r1, r2);
}
```

This compiles with no errors!

The expected error only happens when I uncomment the `println!`. Why does it let me declare multiple references? Doesn't it make more sense to stop me when I declare multiple mutable references rather than when I use them?

What is going on here? I am using Rust 1.39.0.

Comment: You never use `r1` after `r2`, so the borrow of `s1` by `r1` is implicitly released.

Comment: See also [Rust compiler not always throwing borrowing errors](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57189167/155423); [What changed in Rust that allows this borrow after a mutable borrow?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/57743044/155423); [Why did compiler not error on this mutable borrow when there is an immutable borrowed string slice reference still in scope?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/53954053/155423)