# Why can I get multiple mutable references to a variable in Rust without using unsafe code?

Tags: rust, borrow-checker

I'm reading through the Rust book, and it said the following in [section 4.2](https://doc.rust-lang.org/stable/book/ch04-02-references-and-borrowing.html#the-rules-of-references):

> At any given time, you can have either one mutable reference or any number of immutable references.

However, I was experimenting and discovered that I actually can have more than one mutable reference in the same scope without using any unsafe code:

```rust
fn make_mut(x: &mut i32) -> &mut i32 {
    x
}

fn main() {
    let mut i = 1;
    let ir = &mut i;
    let ir2 = make_mut(ir);
    *ir2 = 2;
    println!("{}", *ir);
}
```

Output:

```
2
```

What's going on here? Was the Rust book oversimplifying things? Is there a better source of information on the Rust borrow checker geared for inexperienced Rust programmers than the Rust book?

Comment: *same scope* ≠ *any given time*. You made an incorrect assumption.

Comment: See also [Why doesn't Rust stop me from declaring multiple mutable references?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/59380414/155423)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mutable references are non-`Copy`, so after you passed `ir` to `make_mut` it was moved and does not exist any more:

```
fn make_mut(x: &mut i32) -> &mut i32 {
    x
}

fn main() {
    let mut i = 1;
    let ir = &mut i;
    let ir2 = make_mut(ir);
    *ir = 3; // error here
    *ir2 = 2;
    println!("{}", *ir);
}
```

In your particular case, reborrowing happens with `ir`; that's how Rust modifyies your code:

```
fn make_mut(x: &mut i32) -> &mut i32 {
    x
}

fn main() {
    let mut i = 1;
    let ir = &mut i;
    let ir2 = make_mut(&mut *ir); // rust replaces raw `ir` with reborrowed mutable reference to dereferenced `ir`
    *ir2 = 2;
    println!("{}", *ir);
}
```

There will still be a compile error if you try to use both mutable references at once.

Comment: It's still dereferenced in `println!("{}", *ir);` though. Does it go into some weird half-existing state after being moved? Schrodinger's ref?

Comment: I've updated my answer to explain a little bit about reborrowing.

Comment: Ah okay saw your edit. I haven't heard of reborrowing. Do you know where I might be able to read more about it? I'm on Ch. 19 of the Rust book and I don't think it's been mentioned.

Comment: Okay for anyone reading this in the future, this issue may be helpful: https://github.com/rust-lang/reference/issues/788

Comment: It's just a little trick of Rust: every mutable reference is treated as `&mut *my_mut_ref`. But it works only for exact types. So if you have any generic `<T>` and `&mut T`, then if you try to use that mutable reference, reborrowing will not happen.